# Display SQL query data in grid vaadin

Tags: sql, oracle, grid, vaadin

I would like to display the result of my SQL query in a grid vaadin

I can get the data from my toto table

But I can't display them in a grid

How to do it?

```
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

    private CustomerService service = CustomerService.getInstance();
    private Grid<Customer> grid = new Grid<>(Customer.class);

    public MainView() {
        /*Button button = new Button("Click me",
                event -> Notification.show("Clicked!"));
        add(button);*/

        //BDD
        try{
            //step1 load the driver class
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

            //step2 create  the connection object
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxx:1521:chan","xxx","xxx");

            //step3 create the statement object
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

            //step4 execute query
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from toto");
            while(rs.next())
                System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));


            //step5 close the connection object
            con.close();

        }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}



        //GRID
        grid.setColumns("firstName", "lastName", "status");

        add(grid);

        setSizeFull();

        updateList();
    }

    public void updateList()
    {
        grid.setItems(service.findAll());
    }
}
```

I modified my code by adding a grid, now I would like to understand how I can display the results of my query in my grid

Comment: This question is not written in English, and therefore does not meet the minimum requirements for Stack Overflow. All posts on this site are [required to be in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/).

Comment: Do you know how to create a grid? https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/grid

Comment: It's hard to tell where you actually have your problem.  There seems basically to be no attempt to actually work with the grid but only some "old school" jdbc-tutorial stuff? Could you please be more specific, what problems you're facing.  E.g. add the errors you get or what does not work.  Have you checked out e.g. https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/tutorial/overview and https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/tutorial/database-access for low barrier code?

Comment: I guess the problem is related to not knowing how to get the data out of the ResultSet. The println is kind of getting there, but the next steps forward be would be to 1) create a new ArrayList to store the result, 2) create some new objects of the proper type (Person?) in the while loop, 3) populate the new object with data from the ResultSet, 4) add the new Person objects to the ArrayList in the while loop and 5) put the ArrayList into the Grid with grid.setItems(arrayList)

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a Grid of the type Customer with `Grid<Customer>`. This means the Grid can be set up by providing a List of Customers. Using your code example:

```
        List<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            //step1 load the driver class
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

            //step2 create  the connection object
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxx:1521:chan","xxx","xxx");

            //step3 create the statement object
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

            //step4 execute query
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from toto");
            while(rs.next()) {
                Customer customer = new Customer();
                customer.setFirstName(rs.getString(2));
                customer.setLastName(rs.getString(3));
                customer.setStatus(rs.getInt(1));
                customerList.add(customer);
            }


            //step5 close the connection object
            con.close();

        }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}



        //GRID
        grid.setColumns("firstName", "lastName", "status");
        grid.setItems(customerList);
        add(grid);
```